# ¿Existen enums anidadas en Java?

Tags: java, tipos, enum

Quiero hacer un enum de paises a los cuales pueda acceder a sus estados, algo similar a esto:

```
public enum SomeEnum {

     ARGENTINA {
       BUENOS_AIRES;
     }

     UNITED_STATES {
       CALIFORNIA, FLORIDA, NEW_YORK, ALASKA;
     }

}

SomeEnum state1 = SomeEnum.ARGENTINA.BUENOS_AIRES
SomeEnum state2 = SomeEnum.UNITED_STATES.CALIFORNIA;
```

Comment: Por algún motivo no quieres hacer SomeEnum.US_CALIFORNIA, SomeEnum.ARG_BuenosAires?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer lo mismo si en lugar del enum que has llamado "SomeEnum", usas una clase con miembros estáticos.

```
package pruebas;

class PAIS {
    static enum ARGENTINA{BUENOS_AIRES};
    static enum UNITED_STATES { CALIFORNIA, FLORIDA, NEW_YORK, ALASKA; }
}

public class Pruebas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enum estado1 = PAIS.ARGENTINA.BUENOS_AIRES;
        Enum estado2 = PAIS.UNITED_STATES.ALASKA;
    }
}
```

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con esto.

Comment: Técnicamente responde la pregunta. Pero yendo un poco más de fondo, me parece un diseño muy extraño.

Comment: Hola @LuiggiMendoza no se en que contexto se esta usando este código, habrá más formas de hacerlo.    Si lo que no entiendes es la clase static, es una clase normal, pero los miembros de la clase no tienes que instanciarlos, por eso en el main puedes acceder a esos miembros sin crear ninguna variable, como si fuera un enum.  Saludos.

Comment: Claro que entiendo el código, es más hasta podrías colocar la clase como `final` para que nadie la extienda y ponerle un constructor privado para que nadie pueda crear instancias, indicando que solo tiene constantes o clases/enums con más constantes. Nuevamente, técnicamente responde la pregunta (y tienes mi voto por ello), pero yendo más a fondo, me intriga un poco más el problema de fondo a resolver (del cual no se conoce) y si el diseño mostrado aquí será el adecuado.

Comment: A mi también me parece un tanto extraño, pero creo que es una buena solución al problema que expone el op.

Comment: Más bien, creo que tus `enum`s internos deberían ser `public`, sino las clases de otros paquetes no podrán acceder a ellos.